# Importing csv to mysql: file name as value in column

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have a file named: `2018-10-18_trx_result.csv` and `2018-10-11_another-file.csv`. How can I make my filename as value inside my column as `date format`?.

**Example:** I import `2018-10-18_trx_result.csv` so `2018-10-18` should be the value in my `date_sourced` column like this:

```
|date_sourced| sha1 | vsdt | trendx |notes|
-------------------------------------------
|2018-10-18  | SHA1 | vsdt | trendx |notes| #how can I remove the headers too?
|2018-10-18  | value| value| value  |value|
|2018-10-18  | value| value| value  |value|
```

**Here is my code to import my csv to mysql database:**

```
import csv
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                          host='localhost',
                          database='jeremy_db')
file = open('C:\\Users\\trendMICRO\\Desktop\\OJT\\test.csv', 'rb')  
csv_data = csv.reader(file)

cursor = mydb.cursor()

for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test(sha1, vsdt,trendx,notes )' 'VALUES(%s, %s, %s,%s)',row)

# close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print("Done")
```

Also how can I exclude the headers when I upload them to my table?.

Comment: Use: `date_sourced = '2018-10-18_trx_result.csv'[:10]`

Answer (score 0):

This can help. Use '`regular expression`' `re`.

```
import re
fileName=['2018-10-18_trx_result.csv','2018-10-11_another-file.csv']
for m in fileName:
    print [re.findall("([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})", m)[0], m]
```

result:

```
['2018-10-18', '2018-10-18_trx_result.csv']
['2018-10-11', '2018-10-11_another-file.csv']
```

Comment: i think this is a good solution but , it doesn't get the date only

Comment: Okay, I have modified it now. Have a look and say what you think

Comment: thanks, now i can get the date format, my problem now is how can i insert it